# I am trying to implement sphinx model for regional language. but I am getting this error in decoding

Tags: android, ubuntu, pocketsphinx

MODULE: DECODE Decoding using models previously trained
        Decoding 226 segments starting at 0 (part 1 of 1) 
        0% ERROR: FATAL: "batch.c", line 821: PocketSphinx decoder init failed

ERROR: This step had 1 ERROR messages and 0 WARNING messages.  Please check the log file for details.
ERROR: Failed to start pocketsphinx_batch
        Aligning results to find error rate
Can't open /home/pratik/Desktop/SVARA_ubntu/Svara3/result/Svara3-1-1.match
word_align.pl failed with error code 65280 at /usr/lib/sphinxtrain/scripts/decode/slave.pl line 173.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

I have changed $CFG_CD_TRAIN to 'no', so need to change $DEC_CFG_MODEL_NAME to "$CFG_EXPTNAME.ci_cont" from your sphinx_train.cfg

I think this will save time of others.